# How can you configure an Azure Table Connection String for NLog using Settings variables?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, nlog

I have an issue where I need to write logs to an Azure table using Nlog, but the connection string could change depending on the environment (i.e. Dev/UAT etc.), so I need to take this from another config file. My Nlog 'targets' section currently looks like the following:

```
<targets>
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${var:configDir}\nlog-all.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />
    <target xsi:type="AzureTableStorage"
        connectionString="${var:myNLogConnectionString}"
        name="NLogAzureTable"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"            
        tableName="MyTestLogs"
        logTimeStampFormat="O" />
</targets>
```

My Api looks as follows:

```cs
ILoggerFactory logger = new LoggerFactory().AddNLog();
var nlogConfigSection = config.Settings.Sections["MyService_NlogSettings"];
LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("nlog.config");

LogManager.Configuration.Variables["configDir"] = nlogConfigSection.Parameters["FileLocation"].Value;
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myNLogConnectionString"] = nlogConfigSection.Parameters["environmentNLogConnectionString"].Value;
```

I can see from debugging that the config.settings values are all being retrieved as required, and even that the variables in the configuration are all being populated appropriately. I've found that if I write locally to the 'allfile' text file, it's managing to retrieve and populate 'configDir', since that's where the text file appears!
However, if I switch to using Azure, I can see as previously mentioned that the variable is being set in the Configuration, but when I look at the Nlog Internal Log file, I can see that it thinks that the connection string is blank.

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?!? I've seen solutions for similar problems, but they invariably seem to involve doing what I've already done, but I'm getting no joy!

Comment: You can now read directly from appsettings.json with `${configsetting}` : https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Maybe good idea if you explain what NLog target you using (Adding link to the nuget-package in your question). Could also post this an issue on github for the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
ILoggerFactory logger = new LoggerFactory().AddNLog();
var nlogConfigSection = config.Settings.Sections["MyService_NlogSettings"];

// Configure global settings before loading NLog.config
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("configDir", nlogConfigSection.Parameters["FileLocation"].Value); 
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myNLogConnectionString", nlogConfigSection.Parameters["environmentNLogConnectionString"].Value); 

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("nlog.config");
```

With the following NLog.config, replacing `${var` with `${gdc`:

```xml
<targets>
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${var:configDir}\nlog-all.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />
    <target xsi:type="AzureTableStorage"
        connectionString="${gdc:myNLogConnectionString}"
        name="NLogAzureTable"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"            
        tableName="MyTestLogs"
        logTimeStampFormat="O" />
</targets>
```

Comment: Genius! This does exactly what I need for the connection string.  

On a side note, despite previously reading that you couldn't use variables for log levels in the nlog.config, I was hoping I might be able to use it for these as well, but it unfortunately doesn't work. Ah well, can't have everything, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'd love to vote this up, but I'm such a new user that I don't have those privileges yet...